# How to set fieldLabel width to 50%. Cross-browser solution

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I need to set `fieldLabel` `width` to `50%` for all fields inside my tabpanel. The solution should be cross-browser and the result should look like this:

[image]

I now have this code.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function() {
        var mypanel=Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
            layout:'border',
            border:false,
            items:[{
                region:'center',
                xtype:'tabpanel',
                border:false,
                items:[{
                    title:'tab1',
                    bodyStyle:'padding:4px',
                    layout:'anchor',
                    defaults:{
                        anchor:'100%'
                    },
                    items:[{
                        xtype:'textfield',
                        fieldLabel:'Label'
                    },{
                        xtype:'fieldset',
                        title:'Title',  
                        defaults:{
                            anchor:'100%'
                        },                                  
                        items:[{
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel:'Label 2'
                        }]
                    }]
                },{
                    title:'tab1',
                    bodyStyle:'padding:4px',
                    layout:'anchor',
                    defaults:{
                        anchor:'100%'
                    },
                    items:[{
                        xtype:'textfield',
                        fieldLabel:'Label 3'
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{ 
            width:400,
            height:300,
            layout:'fit',
            items:mypanel
        }).show();
    }
});         
});
```

If I set `labelWidth` to `100%`, then I get a desired result in FF, but not in Chrome. If I set `labelWidth` to `50%`, then it's ok in Chrome, when I click on a tab for the first time, but if I click for the second time fields get larger. So, I need a true cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just using css?
Add a class to both textfields (or override .x-form-item) and add the following css (you might have to use !important to override the default css):

> ```
> .x-form-item {
>     width: 100%;
> }
> .x-form-item label {
>     width: 50%;
> }
> .x-form-item .x-form-item-body {
>     width: 50%;
>     min-width: 100px;
> }
> ```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Actually I found another cross-browser solution - just to set `width` property to `100%`, even though documentation says, that it should be numeric (I may be mistaken)

Comment: Yeah, you can use anything you'ld use in css.. even using px or dp as units.